# Finding Lagrange multiplier

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, least-squares

Suppose I'm looking for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C^{M\times 1}}$ such that:

$$\mathbf{x}=\text{arg}\min_\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{a+Ax}\|_2^2+\lambda\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2~,$$
where $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{C^{N\times 1}}$ and $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C^{N\times M}}$. For $\lambda > 0$ there exists a solution $\mathbf{x=-(A^HA+\lambda I)^{-1}A^Ha}$ that satisfies $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2=\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is known.

My question is how do I find the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ in the solution above that satisfies $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2=\alpha$.

Comment: There is no analytical solution. Are you content with a numerical method?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yes no analytical solution exists. I did use an optimization package to find $\mathbf{x}$ numerically, but I'd also like to know $\lambda$ that gives me that numerical solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to solve the following equation:
$$a^TA(A^HA+\lambda I)^{-1}A^Ha = \alpha$$
You're going to have to do this numerically; say, using [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). If you're willing to do an SVD, you can simplify a bit: let $A=U\Sigma V^H$, where $\Sigma = \mathop{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n)$, and define $\tilde{a}=A^Ha$. Then
$$a^TA(A^HA+\lambda I)^{-1}A^Ha = \tilde{a}^H \Sigma(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma \tilde{a} = \sum_i \frac{\sigma_i^2|\tilde{a}_i|^2}{\sigma_i^2+\lambda} = \alpha$$
You can apply any root-finding method to this, or you could multiply through to obtain a polynomial equation in $\lambda$ to solve.

Comment: Thx for the solution, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^*$ be a minimizer for the optimization problem
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} & \quad \|a + Ax \|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad \|x\|_2^2 \leq \alpha.
\end{align*}
Let $\lambda^*$ be a Lagrange multiplier for the constraint
$\| x\|_2^2 \leq \alpha$.  (Many numerical solvers such as CVX return $\lambda^*$ as output when solving this optimization problem.)

Then, by the KKT conditions, $x^*$ is a minimizer (with respect to $x$) of the Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
L(x,\lambda^*) =
\| a + Ax \|_2^2 + \lambda^* \|x\|_2^2.
\end{equation}

Comment: In other words, your answer is "use a different solver that actually returns the Lagrange multiplier, so you don't have to do this second step" :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant My default answer to optimization questions is "use CVX".  haha.

Comment: Who am I to argue with that? :-)

Comment: @littleO Thx for suggesting an easier route. I'm using a different solver, does CVX spells out "lagrange multiplier = ". I guess my question what's the identifier for the lagrange multiplier?. I haven't used CVX before.

Comment: @user34626 CVX makes it very easy to get the values of the Lagrange multipliers.  I think you just write "lambda: sum(x.^2) <= alpha" when you're writing the constraint for CVX.  The CVX documentation explains it clearly.